# Interpreting a string received from a socket

Tags: python, string, sockets

I am trying to interpret a string that I have received from a socket. The first set of data is seen below:

```
2 -> 1

1 -> 2

2 -> 0

0 -> 2

0 -> 2

1 -> 2

2 -> 0
```

I am using the following code to get the numerical values:

```
for i in range(0,len(data)-1):
    if data[i] == "-":
        n1 = data[i-2]
        n2 = data[i+3]
        moves.append([int(n1),int(n2)])
```

But when a number greater than 9 appears in the data, the program only takes the second digit of that number (eg. with 10 the program would get 0). How would I get both of the digits from the code while maintaining the ability to get single digit numbers?

Comment: Rather than apologising for bad formatting, try to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just grab one character on each side ..

for the second value you can make it like this: data[i+3,len(data)-1]

for the first one:                            : data[0,i-2]

Answer (score 0):

Use the split() function

```
numlist = data[i].split('->')
moves.append([int(numlist[0]),int(numlist[1])])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume each line is available as a (byte) string in a variable named `line`. If it's a whole bunch of lines then you can split it into individual lines with

```
lines = data.splitlines()
```

and work on each line inside a `for` statement:

```
for line in lines:
    # do something with the line
```

If you are confident the lines will always be correctly formatted the easiest way to get the values you want uses the [string `split` method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). A full code starting from the data would then read like this.

```
lines = data.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    first, _, second = line.split()
    moves.append([int(first), int(second)])
```